# Start another application in my layout

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout

i'm building an application and need a layout that shows google maps navigation, there is any way to open the Google Maps app from in my application?
(i dont want an intent to open the normal Google Maps app..)

for example -

[image: example]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Launching Google Maps Directions via an intent on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662531/launching-google-maps-directions-via-an-intent-on-android)

Comment: [this is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662531/launching-google-maps-directions-via-an-intent-on-android) what you need

Comment: "but I don't want to put the Google Maps into my application - instead, I want to launch it using an Intent." - i want to put the Google Maps into my application..

Comment: and why you need to do that?

Comment: my layout have some functions that the google maps application doesnt have.. (for example fade in and out every 10 sec)

Comment: you can get [directions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro) but  [Navigation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents#launch_turn-by-turn_navigation) support is via google map application only.

Comment: you want to open google map inside your application using intent??

Comment: i want to open google maps (or any other app) inside my application

Comment: I think you could use cross-platform to develop. Using html, js to develop is the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wanty to use Google Maps app, you will have to implement your very own map logic using map view.

You can read [map view documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/) to lear how to use these api.

Using these approach you will be able to use any customization you want on your maps, **BUT** you will have to take care of every details.