# How to immediately start Google Maps Navigation given an address?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

I am interested in creating a button where the button will immediately launch the Google Maps app and begin driving navigation to a specific address. Is this possible? If so, what is the API?

I'd like for it to immediately begin navigation, without forcing the user to choose between different route options.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662531/launching-google-maps-directions-via-an-intent-on-android

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I discovered the solution. In order to immediately invoke Google Maps to directly navigate, simply perform the following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
    Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=an+address+city"));
```