# issue with setting up a map

Tags: android, google-maps

i generated mapview

[image]

first of all i want to know the actual name of this view in the rectangle, 
and my question is when i open my map activity, map appear on screen, but this view in the rectangle is not appearing, its only appear when i click on my robot, so how do i do that make view comes up when activity start, not on my robot click, help me, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This control known as **Map toolbar**

By default, a toolbar appears at the bottom right of the map when a user taps a marker. The toolbar gives the user quick access to the Google Maps mobile app.

You can enable and disable the toolbar by calling UiSettings.setMapToolbarEnabled(boolean).

For more details visit: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/controls#map_toolbar

Comment: its still appear when i click on my marker, its not working as that i want, by the way,, thank you for the knowledge.

Comment: toolbar can't be appear before user action on marker. From doc,  toolbar appears at the bottom right of the map when a user taps a marker, you can disable.

Comment: By default this toolbar is enabled.

Comment: sure,, i can only up your answer, but not mark as accepted, bcz i still thinking there is a way to do that, i m still searching, if i am satisfied then i will mark as accepted

Comment: trick to achieve your result, add your button and launch google map app via intent and pass current location.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662531/launching-google-maps-directions-via-an-intent-on-android

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you make them appear by default and you shouldn't want to.
Those buttons are for `Navigation` and `Show on Google Maps` (both open Maps application) actions which both need a selected location to be relevant thus appearing when you select a location.