# How to change or set your GPS location on Android

Tags: java, android, gps

I have an Android tablet that does not have gps
how can programmatically enter latitude and longitude And see virtual position on the android google maps.

```
setlocation(double latitude, double longitude)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Google maps api? If not, I think it would solve your problem. It has the option of moving the map camera to whatever position you like. You would need to provide the latitude and longitude.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/

The link also has all the necessary code. I'm assuming you will be getting the location through the tablet's network provider.

EDIT: So, assuming you'll be having the latitude and longitude before hand and you wish to open the Google maps app - you should use the intent feature in android. It would go like this -

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=20.344,34.34&daddr=20.5666,45.345"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Here saddr and daddr are start and end coordinates. Also, I got this from here - 
[Launching Google Maps Directions via an intent on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662531/launching-google-maps-directions-via-an-intent-on-android)

NOTE: The above code will open the google maps app and won't show you the map in your very own app.

Answer (score 0):

i use this and worked for my

```
                            Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q="+f);

                        Intent i2 = new Intent();
                        i2.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
                        i2.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        i2.setData(gmmIntentUri);
                        i2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                        context.startActivity(i2);
```

f = lat and lon f="0.0000,0.0000"

Answer (score -1):

I want to get lat and lon from a string and send be as gps data and refresh it in the service. Update when send new string
and show up on the Google Map app in tablet.