# open google Maps with given directions (route)

Tags: java, android, google-maps, navigation, directions

Is there a way in Andorid Studio to open the Google Maps App with already given parameters for routing (directions). Like there are many possible routes to get to your destination. I want to select or create my own routing to the destination and then starting Google Maps for Navigation.

Could you please help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Launching Google Maps Directions via an intent on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662531/launching-google-maps-directions-via-an-intent-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

Answer is taken from [Launching Google Maps Directions via an intent on Android.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662531/launching-google-maps-directions-via-an-intent-on-android)

```
Uri.Builder directionsBuilder = new Uri.Builder()
                .scheme("https")
                .authority("www.google.com")
                .appendPath("maps")
                .appendPath("dir")
                .appendPath("")
                .appendQueryParameter("api", "1")
                .appendQueryParameter("origin", "28.7041" + "," + "77.1025")
                .appendQueryParameter("destination", "18.5204" + "," + "73.8567");

        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, directionsBuilder.build()));
```

If you want origin as your current location, remove below line:

```
.appendQueryParameter("origin", "28.7041" + "," + "77.1025")
```