# Open different websites in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-recyclerview

I'm working on an app to help my local PokemonGO community and I'm having one last problem that I can't find the answer.
I made a RecyclerView where I can add as many gyms as I want (this is working fine), and then, when the user clicks in that gym, I want the app to send to the location on Google Maps.

I created the following interface and the method on the adapter:

```
public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(int position);
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
    mListener = listener;
}
```

And this on the ViewHolder:

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (listener != null) {
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                            listener.onItemClick(position);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

And here is where I have the problem, that I don't know how to send the user to Maps

```
mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new GimnasioAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int position) {
                String maps = gimnasiosLista.get(position).getURL();

            }
        });
```

Edit: The answer is here [Launching Google Maps Directions via an intent on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662531/launching-google-maps-directions-via-an-intent-on-android)

Comment: What is the format of your url?

Comment: What do you mean about format? It's a link

Comment: Is this what you need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662531/launching-google-maps-directions-via-an-intent-on-android ?

Comment: That was exactly what I needed, so I realized that I made the difficult part without noticing and I was stuck on an intent.