# Unable to open Google Maps link in Android web view app

Tags: java, android

I have created a webview app of my site in Android Studio. Could someone please look into the code and solve the issue. This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if (url == null || url.startsWith("http://") || url.startsWith("https://")) return false;

                try {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    return true;
                }
            }
        });
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://xyz.in/admin_login.php");
    }

    public void onBackPressed(){
        if(webView.canGoBack()){
            webView.goBack();
        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

When WhatsApp icon is clicked, it's opening in WhatsApp application,but when **view location** is clicked, the button is not responding. Please help on this issue.

Please find the attached image for your reference
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Launching Google Maps Directions via an intent on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662531/launching-google-maps-directions-via-an-intent-on-android)

Comment: No..view location html link shall be similar to https://maps.app.goo.gl/HUo3dVhJbZ2oQ85J7 which shall be dynamically generated..so I could not understand how this can be implemented