# Launch Google Maps from app

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

I have setup my app to launch Google maps to a set location using the code below, but the map displays zoomed full and you cant see any roads you have to zoom out manually to see anything.   How can I set the zoom level with the code below I've tried setZoom(16); but this has no effect.

```
if (mapnav == 10) {
   String uri = "geo: 53.777969,-1.571474";        
   setZoom(16);

   Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));

   startActivity(i);}
```

Also can I launch into Directions instead of the map

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify a zoom level in your URI with for example `"geo: 53.777969,-1.571474?z=23"`

> **Google Maps**
>
> ```
> geo:latitude,longitude
> geo:latitude,longitude?z=zoom
> geo:0,0?q=my+street+address
> geo:0,0?q=business+near+city
> ```
>
> *VIEW*
>
> Opens the Maps application to the given location or query. The Geo URI scheme (not fully supported) is currently under development.
>   The z field specifies the zoom level. A zoom level of 1 shows the whole Earth, centered at the given lat,lng. A zoom level of 2 shows a quarter of the Earth, and so on. The highest zoom level is 23. A larger zoom level will be clamped to 23.

For the google navigation part you can use `"google.navigation:q="+location` where `location` are the coordinates. The intent `Intent.ACTION_VIEW`.

---

**Resources :**

- [developer.android.com - Intents List: Invoking Google Applications on Android Devices](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html)

**On the same topic :**

- [Google Navigation (Android 1.6) intent callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304735/google-navigation-android-1-6-intent-callback)

Comment: Genius thanks had a person tell me this was not possible earlier so I tried asking about directions and finally got to navigator Thank you Colin

Comment: Great!! A huge Thums-up for such a Beautiful answer, really appreciate your efforts :)